# how to store image as string and then return it yo image using java?

Tags: java, android, inputstream

how can i convert image to inputstream then to string , after that reversing the operations where to convert string to inputsrream then ti image format (drawable) in android ..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image to Byte Array to String (and vice versa)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084036/image-to-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

To represent a byte stream as a string, you could use [Base64 encoding](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).