# Image to Byte Array to String (and vice versa)

Tags: java, image-processing, arrays, inputstream

I'd like to convert an image into a byte array, then convert that byte array into a string. Also, I'd then like to convert that string back to a byte array, and finally back to an image. How might I go about accomplishing this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Which of these steps is causing you the most trouble?

Comment: If you tell us why then people may consider suggesting alternatives, as maybe this isn't really the solution to the problem - you could be more elaborate, though.

Comment: These two links can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580038/byte-array-to-image-file

Comment: Another link that can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth image to bytearray and vice versa

Comment: Why do you want to make the byte array into a `String`? Image data is not character data and won't work well as a `String` directly, though using some encoding like Base64 will work.

Answer (score 7):

1. Use `ImageIO.write(..)` and pass a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then call `stream.toByteArray()` - you have the bytes.
2. Use base64 or hex to represent the byte array as string - [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) has `Base64` and `Hex` which allow conversion in both directions. So now you have the string
3. See 2 - convert from string to byte array. Now you have the `byte[]` again.
4. Use `ImageIO.read(..)` and pass a `new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)`

(for point 2 and 3 you *can* use `new String(bytes, "utf-8")` and `string.getBytes("utf-8")`, but prefer base64)

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-image-to-byte-array-convert-byte-array-to-image/  like this ? but i'm using jdk 6 but i can't find the class ImageIO !!

Comment: @adham - `javax.imageio.ImageIO`. Use an IDE to organize your imports, it would find it immediately.

Comment: @adham - yes, exactly like shown in the link. Just don't use the `com.sun..internal` - get apache commons-codec.

Comment: @adham - did you import it.. ?